# Most important Browsers for mobiles and Tablets

Tags: responsive-web-design

To whom it may concern:
I am developing a responsive site based on joomla, making it responsive.
I have fixed everything in Chrome and FF as main broswers for tablets and mobiles
What are other browsers of use for mobile and tablets? for instance is it necessary to fix my site and test it for safari and ie too?
Kian William

Comment: It depends on your target users. A website I was developing several years ago had the unfortunate situation where most of the users were using internet explorer 6. Ordinarily I wouldn't have touched it with a stick, but you have to cater for your users.

Comment: The website is for kids, airplane kits for kids, I have no problem with responsive, in chrome, FF, opera, safari and ie it is working fine in all pages till 311px width.  under this width, some differences starts to be shown, I do not think it is really worth attention.

Comment: Depends on your site requirements. You should definitely support IE11, but have a good think about whether or not you wish to support anything below that. Older IE versions can be a massive PITA

Answer (score 1):

Apple Safari is worth testing for simply because of the amount of iPhone users out there.

You can avoid most browser issues nowadays by using normalize.css and validating your HTML and CSS.  If you are having to write fixes for each browser, do that first.

Comment: As I mentioned above I do not have problem with any browser till 311px width. No use of normalize.css , using strong ingenius jquery, and general css syntaxes have worked fine.

Comment: 320px is the smallest you have to worry about - https://mydevice.io/devices/

Comment: That is very good and long live science

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, Safari and UC browser are the top browsers as per their usage. Being Chrome a major browser by usage(50%+), you should test it by default.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers

All apple devices uses Safari as a default browser and most users are still using it. So it would be good to have your application tested at least in Safari if your target user base includes Apple devices (iPhone, iPad etc).

Comment: I did opera and  safari too, till the 311px width I had no problem